# Understanding trampoline optimisation for recursive functions

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming

I have got the following trampoline implementation:

```
function trampoline(f) {
    while (f && f instanceof Function) {

        f = f.apply(f.context, f.args);

    }
    return f;
}
```

And it works likewise, example being factorial:

```
function factorial(n) {
    function recur(n, acc) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return acc;
        } else {
            return recur.bind(null, n-1, n*acc);
        }
    }
    return trampoline(recur.bind(null, n, 1));
}
```

The problem is that I don't understand how `f.context` and `f.args` are passed in as arguments, those are properties that clearly can't be found on recurred function inside the trampoline when i, for instance, try to access and `console.log` them. It then logs `undefined` values.

What is the mechanism of this particular implementation that is passing arguments of the function?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the advantage of using trampoline as opposed to just calling the "vanilla" function?

Comment: Javascript does not optimise tail recursion by default so its really easy to exceed the stack limit and exhaust performance.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine, can you clarify the problem?

Comment: The problem is as stated, understanding how f.context and f.args are taken as recursive arguments and how the function is accessing them. As when you try to log them during trampoline they would show undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function), function objects do not have properties called `args` and `context`, and that's why they appear as `undefined` in the console log. Inside the function itself, you can access these values in the `arguments` and `this` objects, but **they are not visible from the outside** in bound functions (or unbound functions).

The reason your code works is because the `apply` parameters are appended if the function is bound with the parameters. When you `bind` a function, you can bind only the context (this) or the context and the parameters. If you bind the context and the parameters, when you `apply` or `call` that function, the parameters you pass in will be appended at the end of the parameters list. In your particular case, you are doing...

```
f = f.apply(undefined, undefined);
```

... and the resulting parameters for f would be:

```
[...parametersWhenTheFunctionWasBound, undefined, undefined]
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that there's no such properties hence the question.

So it could be null or undefined as well or a plain function call as that bind just delays execution as a quasi partial application attempt.

Comment: The arguments array is not ignored, but rather appended to the bound list.